# java could not be run on my machine

Tags: java

I am trying to execute java from command prompt and it always give that

`error: Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working`.

I did a lot of research on fixing this and I uninstalled java and reinstalled it several times but it doesn't help.

Comment: Which operating system do you use and how does the command look like?

Comment: Can you show us the complete error?

Comment: _to execute java from command prompt_ Means what? 
´java -version´ works, or also no?, etc ..